# что такое программная эмуляция прерывания в ОС?

Tags: ос, прерывания

Как это понять и с чем это едят? Как может программа эмулировать прерывание?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Просто делается аналогичный стэк-фрейм возврата, как при прерывании, и передаётся управление на точку входа в прерывание.

Прерывания использовались в DOS драйверами, и программами для работы с внешними устройствами. При появлении той же Windows появился защищённый режим процессора, а позже и 32-битный режим. Емуляция понадобилась для совместимости с написаным раннее софтом.

Для х86  это было бы примерно так:

```
pushf
call far  dword ptr [int_address]
```